# adding property to an existing xcdatamodel crashes Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, xcode4

I am trying to add a new property/attribute to an existing xcdatamodel and when I do so it always gives me this spinny beach ball spinner and it crashes. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the system? When I suffer from XCode hanging, I restart my Mac and it solves the problem.

Comment: I did all that and it still crashes